# Sortable receive event dynamic

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using **jQuery UI Sortable** to make a menu builder and i have a little problem when i try to execute the `:receive Event` with dynamic contents. (Receive Event are not executed when try to add something on dynamic content).

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$( ".parentmenu, .submenu" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".connected",
    receive: function( event, ui ) {
        var $item = $(ui.item);
        $item.addClass('dropdown');
                $item.find('a:first').addClass('dropdown-toggle');
                $item.find('a:first').attr('data-toggle', 'dropdown');
                $item.find('a:first').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
                var x = '<ol class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left connected submenu ui-sortable"><div class="menu-builder-tools"><i class="icon-info3"></i> Drag and Drop an element here</div></ol>';
                $(x).appendTo($item).sortable({connectWith: 'connected'});

        alert('received');
    }
});
});
```

Can anybody give me a hand please ?
**[MY JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/webly/myzkqgjc/17/)**

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
Replace: $(x).appendTo($item).sortable({connectWith: 'connected'});
With: $(x).appendTo($item).sortable({connectWith: 'connected', receive: function( event, ui ) {alert('test');}});
```